# Replace first occurence of a word with link

Tags: plugin-development

i want to extend automatically the first occurence of a word in all of my WordPress Blog Posts with a link. I found a code (on this site here: http://www.guru-20.info/worter-in-posts-ersetzen/) , that should do the replace, but how can i extend that, so that only the first occurence is replaced?

Thanks!
Rene

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 function guru20_ReplaceWords($text){
 $replace = array('WordPress Codex' =&gt; '<a href="http:/codex.wordpress.com">WordPress Codex [EN]</a>',
             'WPRecipes'=&gt; '<a href="http://www.wprecipes.com" target="_blank">WPRecipes [EN]</a>',
             'f.php' =&gt; 'In die Datei functions.php einfügen.');
 $text = str_replace_first(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'guru20_ReplaceWords');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'guru20_ReplaceWords');

function str_replace_first($from, $to, $subject)
 {
   $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';
    return preg_replace($from, $to, $subject, 1);
 }
```

You can try with `preg_replace`